# Why am I getting this error while typing the command- makemigrations

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
```

I don't know why I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Blank/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "Blank/manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Django\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Django\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Django\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Django\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Django\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, 
in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'products'
```

Please if someone can help or find a solution for the above error. I have this app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings. It still isn't working.

Comment: Make sure to add products app to settings in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: please edit the post formatting the erro as well

Comment: have you registered your model in `admin`

Comment: you should use float method in price filed (check my answer)

Comment: I have added my app to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.

Comment: It still isn't working.

Comment: Do you have the error with `./manage.py shell` too ? NB: import errors messages can be misleading, you actually this message whatever prevents your module from being imported.

Comment: No I don't have error with `./manage.py` shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (in models.py)

```
price = models.FloatField()
```

if didnt work then share your other files also like views.py file

Comment: @YashMarmat please don't suggest using floats for prices - prices are not floats, they are decimals. And it has nothing to do with the OP's error actually.

Comment: i know my main motive is to let him use decimal value (for a price tag lets say of 99.99 $) and wanted him to show us his view.py file to help him in solving this error in right way.

Comment: @AntrikshVerma share your project path, settings.py file and views.py file